# Can I use a list as a value to an AWS resource tag?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tags, amazon-iam

I want to use my EC2 Instances tags for access control. I plan to create an IAM policy having tag-based conditions. It works fine with one tag and matching that tag in IAM policy.

But my question is that can i use a list in my EC2 instance tag value and IAM policy will check for all values (might be comma separated)?

Comment: No, it's a string value. Why do you need it to be multi-valued, as opposed to having multiple tags each with a single value? You may be trying to solve your permissioning needs in a less than ideal way.

Comment: yeah got it thanks.